# How do I import DynamoDB to a Lambda function?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am currently trying to test out an AWS Lambda function where i try to import DynamoDB. However, when i try to test it I get this error

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'dynamodb'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'dynamodb'",
    "Require stack:",
    "- /var/task/index.js",
    "- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js",
    "- /var/runtime/index.js",
    "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)",
    "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)",
    "    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)",
    "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47"
  ]
}
```

This is only my second time working with Lambda functions and I am still learning a lot about them. 
Here is my code from the lambda func

```
var doc = require('dynamodb-doc');
    exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {

        if (event.eventType !=='syncTrigger'){

            callback(JSON.stringify(event));
        }
        if (!(('name' in event.datasetRecords) && ('email' in event.datasetRecords))){
            callback(JSON.stringify(event));
        }
        var name = event.datasetRecords.name.newValue;
        var email = event.datasetRecords.email.newValue;

        var shouldDeleteRecord = (event.datasetRecords.name.op === 'remove') || (event.datasetRecords.email.op === 'remove');

        if (shouldDeleteRecord === true) {
            // do not delete from dynamo DB
            callback(null, event);
        }
        var db = new doc.DynamoDB();

        var params = {'TableName' : 'User', 'Item': {'id' : event.identityId, 'username' : name, 'email_address': email}};

        db.putItem(params,function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('User insert failure', err);
                callback(err);
            } else {
                console.log('User insert success', data);
                callback(null, event);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Looks like that error message was not caused by that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are importing a third-party DynamoDB package named [dynamodb-doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb-doc). This package, like other third-party packages, is not available by default in the Lambda runtime environment.

You can continue to use this package by [bundling it with your upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-package.html).

Or you could switch to the supported, and pre-installed, [AWS Document Client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html).

Comment: Im not even sure where or what the 'dynamodb-doc'  is. Im following a tutorial from an AWS book and the author has not mentioned where to get it or how to upload it.  Do you know where I can download 'dynamodb-doc' if possible and bundle it with the upload to use in my lambda function?

Comment: The page I referenced shows you how to install it. You can install it like any other npm package: `npm install --save dynamodb-doc`. As for bundling it and uploading to Lambda, see the other link I provided. You might, however, be better off simply using the AWS Document Client as then you do not need to upload any additional packages (this assume that the code you've shown is compatible with the AWS Document Client, which it seems to be).

Answer (score 1):

I think you may just need to import the correct module:

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});

// Create the DynamoDB service object
var db = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});
```